# One Random.Randint to assign diff numbers to multiple variables / strings

Tags: python

I would like to have a string of 10 digit random numbers (0,9) printed out in the fashion of:

```
1234567890

1234567890

1234567890

1234567890
```

I would like it to have easily configurable amounts; as in lets say I want to run it for 10 random numbers; quick change of the code then run it for 100

```
1234567890 x 100 #with a new line every time.
```

This is what I have so far, but I can't figure out a way to make it print out multiples:

```py
import random

limit = 10

count = 0

long_number = ""

while count != 10:

    long_number += str(random.randint(0, 9))

    count += 1

print (long_number)
```

Comment: `x = random.randint(0, 9)` and then reuse `x` as many times as you like?

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is what you want:

You can do the following to get the `long_num`, or the random number of a certain length:

```
import random
def print_rand_len(num):
    long_num = ""
    for k in range(num):
        long_num+=str(random.randint(0, 9))
    return int(long_num)
```

This runs as:

```
>>> print_rand_len(5)
83309
>>> print_rand_len(3)
025
>>> print_rand_len(2)
41
>>> print_rand_len(6)
153632
>>>
```

Or you can do this:

```
import random
def print_rand_len(num):
    return random.randint(10**(num-1), (10**num)-1)
```

This runs as:

```
>>> print_rand_len(3)
964
>>> print_rand_len(3)
712
>>> print_rand_len(5)
56699
>>> print_rand_len(2)
72
>>> print_rand_len(13)
6372486964269
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

`random.randint(0, 10**10-1)` Will produce a 10-digit number directly without building it up piecemeal. Creating the loop around it is left as an exercise.

Comment: `'%010d' % random.randint(0, 10**10 - 1)` to get a zero padded string.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you could save yourself a tremendous amount of trouble by grabbing all the random digits at once:

```
print random.randint(0, 9999999999)
```

you could wrap the thing in a function:

```
def rand10():
    print random.randint(0, 9999999999)
```

you could invoke that function in a loop:

```
for i in range(10):
   rand10()
```

you even could wrap *that* in a function:

```
def randN(n):
  for i in range(n):
     rand10()

randN(8)
```